# Matching interface implementation with subtype to implemented type

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

tl;dr: I want the list `List<ComponentDefinition>` in the `CellObjectDefinition` class to be able to be checked with a type check `ICellObjectDefinition<IComponentDefinition>`.
`ComponentDefinition` is unknown at runtime and must therefore be testable with `IComponentDefinition`.

I have the following class:

```cs
public interface IComponentDefinition {}
public class ComponentDefinition : IComponentDefinition {}

public interface ICellObjectDefinition<TCDef>
{
    public List<TCDef> Components { get; set; }
}

public class CellObjectDefinition : ICellObjectDefinition<ComponentDefinition>
{
    public List<ComponentDefinition> Components { get; set; } = new();
}
```

I would have liked to keep the type `ComponentDefinition` in this list as the elements are added dynamically with reflection elsewhere. I want to validate the elements with their associated interfaces.
I don't quite understand why the list doesn't match the interface when I check the list filled with `ComponentDefinition` elements with `ICellObjectDefinition<IComponentDefinition>`.

Even an interface without a generic type does not work:

```cs
public interface ICellObjectDefinition<IComponentDefinition>
{
    public List<IComponentDefinition> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an executable sample code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tpiNgJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depended on the actual use case you can make your interface [`covariant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces):

```
public interface ICellObjectDefinition<out TCDef> : IObjectDefinition
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<TCDef> Components { get;  }
}
```

Which will require some implementation changes (using [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)):

```
public partial class CellObjectDefinition : ObjectDefinition, ICellObjectDefinition<ComponentDefinition>
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<ComponentDefinition> ICellObjectDefinition<ComponentDefinition>.Components => Components; // explicitly implement the interface
    public List<ComponentDefinition> Components { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Full running code - at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3YWwo).